# PHP filter attachment more fast solution?

Tags: php, sql

In my database i have a table for orders and sometime i need to attach files at one specific order.

I find two way for doing this job :

1) storing a file into the attachement dir with manipulated name es. 12-user01-nameoffile.pdf where 12 is number order and after filter all the content of the attachment dir

2) create a db table for storing the attachment information into column orderID. username, filename and filter with sql query

Witch is the more (or best) fast solution for the future when there are many files into the attachment dir ?

**MY PHP CODE FOR FILTER ATTACHMENT DIR**

```
$directory = ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/orders/attachments/");
$rowcount=0;
if (is_dir($directory)) {
   if ($directory_handle = opendir($directory)) {
      while (($file = readdir($directory_handle)) !== false) {
          if((!is_dir($file))&($file!=".")&($file!="..")) { 
              $attachments = explode('-', $file) ;
                 if($attachments[0] == $_SESSION['orderId']) {
                     $rowcount++; 
                 }
          }
     }
      closedir($directory_handle);
   }
}
```

If $rowcount >0 i show an icon with link for the page with attachments list filterd.

Comment: if the ID is in the file name you don't need to store it in the database at all

Comment: how about an `attachment` column in your order table ?

Comment: make sure you have unique value of one of this combination `12-user01-nameoffile`

Comment: @slash197 i know but is more fast (in time and in charge for the server) filter a dir or using a sql query ?

Comment: @ra_htial i think this solution but maybe there are many attachment for the same order

Comment: @geomo then as u suggested, just create a new `attachment` table

Comment: your first solution will solve your problem but i don't see it as a best practice, if you are using a database then all your information should be stored in that database, what if one day you want to generate a report from your database, then u can't use a simple select to get all the report info, you need to search for attachments for every order in your db.

Comment: @ra_htial uhmmmm.. good point! I think i'm using a sql way but my question is unsolved : for the server is more fast read a dir or make a query ?

Comment: this question can't be answered that easily, system configuration / specifications should be taken into consideration, hard-disk also has different I/O capabilities, also records in db ... etc, as far as i can tell once your database start to grow to be sth like 100,000 records, i'm certain that if your database is build right then it will be much faster than scanning a folder.